# What would make an .app bundle not launch a shell script file on double click

Tags: java, macos

I have a tester report that the .app bundle won’t launch on double click on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

This is a Java application that utilizes a shell script to locate the installed java runtime and launch the jar file with the appropriate options.

It will launch correctly if the script file in the Contents/MacOS folder is double clicked, dragged and dropped on terminal, or absolute path to the script is typed into terminal.

The Info.Plist does have the script file name listed under the CFBundleExecutable key.

I have been unable to duplicate the issue on my OS X 10.8 test machine. Any suggestions on what could cause this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the script file inside the bundle is marked as being executable on your tester's computer?

I had issues of the same kind when I copied a bundle app into a virtual machine using drag & drop.
Double clicking the bundle yields no error, the app simply does not start.